# Select consecutive groups using nth-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use nth-child() to select consecutive elements?

I have an ordered list of 24 items. I want to split them up into 4 columns. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
#location-menu li:nth-child(1),
#location-menu li:nth-child(2),
#location-menu li:nth-child(3),
#location-menu li:nth-child(4) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#location-menu li:nth-child(5),
#location-menu li:nth-child(6),
#location-menu li:nth-child(7),
#location-menu li:nth-child(8) {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

As you can see, it's going to get out of control by the 24th item. The best thing to do would use CSS3 columns to split the list into, but it's important that this site work in IE8.

I was hoping for something like this:

```
#location-menu li:nth-child(1-4) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
#location-menu li:nth-child(5-8) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: But IE8 doesn't support `:nth-child()` either...

Comment: I would sacrifice a little bit of semanticity in my markup and split each column into its own ul/ol.

Comment: can you show a jsfiddle for better understanding what you want

Comment: This smells like an acceptable use for a table...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
#location-menu li:nth-child(n+0)  { margin-left: 0;     }
#location-menu li:nth-child(n+5)  { margin-left: 100px; }
#location-menu li:nth-child(n+9)  { margin-left: 200px; }
#location-menu li:nth-child(n+13) { margin-left: 300px; }
/* and so on */
```

Comment: +1 because this is correct, but unless the OP found a way to get it to work in IE8...

Comment: I marked this as correct. I used it in conjunction with  http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ and it should work in IE8.

Comment: Also: `#location-menu li:nth-child(n+0)` can be simplified to `#location-menu li`, or `#location-menu li:nth-child(n)` if you need consistent specificity values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
#location-menu li:nth-child(4n+0){
     margin-left: 0;
}
#location-menu li:nth-child(4n+1){
     margin-left: 100px;
}
...
```

but it will display items by the rows, not by the columns...